# Azure and Consuming REST/JSON Web Services on .dotNet 4.5

Tags: c#, rest, azure, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2015

I am running Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with .NET Framework 4.6. I have to develop a basic client (console or whatever) that connects with REST/JSON Web Services on Azure. I have been given the following sample code, however it does not work (probably because I am so new to this so please excuse me for this!). My question is how do I get this working or do you have any pointers like how do I set up Visual Studio for this (references, packages, etc.). I also believe that I need to call System.IdentityModel instead of Microsoft.IdentityModel but this is all new to me? Is it very hard? Visual Studio seems to recognize any of the methods (even though I have the Build before to framework 3.5).

```
var username = "<username>";
var password = "<password>";

// The Azure AD tenant address
var tenant = "mytest.onmicrosoft.com";

var clientApiId = “111111-222-3333-4444-3232342432";
var appId = “22222-333-5555-1111-3234343434";

var authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, “https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenant);

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var uc = new UserCredential(username, password);
var authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(clientApiId, appId, uc);

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authResult .AccessTokenType, authResult.AccessToken);
```

Thank you very very much in advance for your help/assistance. I am really out of ideas where to start and how to get it working...It looks easy in principle but :-(

Comment: Also, I do not think it is possible to consume them using another technology, let's say directly with JQuery? This is more of a curiosity :-)

Comment: What api endpoint are you trying to hit?  This appears to be a bit over complicated for a simple web request.

Comment: E.g. GET clientapi/v1/devicenetworks, GET clientapi/v1/devicenetworks/{id}

Comment: But it is written that the X-DeviceNetwork and Authorization headers need to be set. The latter is a token provided from Azure AD.